# SocketIO auth and ReactNative

Tags: react-native, authentication, socket.io

I have a module whith the connection:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
import SInfo from 'react-native-sensitive-info';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export const socket = io('http://192...', {
    forceNew: true,
    auth: {
        token: 'eyJhbGciO...'
    },
});
export const SocketContext = createContext(undefined);
```

But my token is saved by lib **react-native-sensitive-info** and i need to get it by

```
await SInfo.getItem('token', {});
```

My question is: How can I use await to get the token I need to export the socket?

Something like this:

```
export const socket = io('http://192...', {
    forceNew: true,
    auth: {
        token: await SInfo.getItem('token', {});
    },
});
```

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
export const socket = async () => {
    const token = await SInfo.getItem('token', {});
    return io('http://192...', {
        forceNew: true,
        auth: {
            token,
        },
    });
}
```

or

```js
export const createSocket = (token) => {
    return io('http://192...', {
        forceNew: true,
        auth: {
            token,
        },
    });
}
```

and then use it in this way:

```js
const token = await SInfo.getItem('token', {});
const socket = createSocket(token)
```